# Open a file on Openshift using Java

Tags: java, openshift

I have a DIY cartridge. My project structure looks like

```
MY_PROJECT
-diy
  -myProgram.jar
  -resources
    -file1, file2...
-.openshift
  -action_hooks
    -start
```

The myProgram.jar uses files from the folder 'resources'.
The code looks like

```
    File imageFolder = new File("resources");
    System.out.println("Image Folder read:"+imageFolder.canRead()); //canRead returns false
    File[] listOfFiles = imageFolder.listFiles(); // here I get null
```

The program runs by action hook 'start':

```
nohup java -jar $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} &
```

The problem is that I'm not able to work with files. 
As described in code comments I get null on listFiles().

If I run the program on Openshift manually(ssh to server/$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/ and run java -jar ...) it works, but it doesn't work via action_hooks.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue with Openshift env variable 'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'.
Instead of using relative path

```
new File("resources");
```

I use absolute

```
String absolutePath = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR");
new File(absolutePath + "diy/resources")
```